# Change icon color when Flutter switches to dark mode

Tags: flutter

How can we change icon colors when switching to dark mode in Flutter?

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: const ExampleDeleteScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

> I applied these changes but the icon color does not change when I switch to dark mode. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
Icon(
          Icons.ac_unit,
          size: 50,
          color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
        ),
```

Comment: thank you very much the code worked smoothly and as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the color of the Icon to follow the ThemeData like this:

```
Icon(
   color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
);
```

Comment: For example, in the dark theme, the icon colors are white. When in light theme, let the icon colors be black. How can I set it.